# Classes and Algebras: Which begat which?

Tags: object-oriented

Way back in the day I took a course on discrete structures and learned about how the mathematical notion of an algebra is akin to the class data type.

But I didn't know enough at the time to ask whether algebras are used to model classes or whether classes are actually derived from algebras (historically, technically...in whatever sense of 'derived' you like).

Wikipedia and Google weren't much help. Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but I think you noticed that algebras (or more precisely algebraic signatures) and classes share a feature, namely that they both can be seen as specifying a bunch of operations. For example the algebraic construct *group* has three operations: multiplication, inverse and the constant $1$. Now you ask if algebras can be used to model classes.

The answer is negative at this point. Classes in the sense of OO programming are complicated beasts. They have features that algebras don't have, in particular computational dynamics. There are other features like inheritance, method overriding, mutable private members that also
don't lend themselves to easy algebraic description. For this reason, purely algebraic sematics of OO languages don't exist.

As to the historic question, I don't know. The development of types goes back to the end of the 19th century, a time when abstract algebra was in nascent form too

Comment: Thanks! That was a long time ago when I was young(er) and stupid(er), so it's possible that in my musings I inferred more from the single shared feature than is justified.

Comment: Well, algebraic methods are important in the semantics of programming languages, usually these days in categorical form, following Lawvere. But algebra is far from the whole story.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is that both begat both.

Garret Birkhoff defined single-sorted universal algebras in 1935, but it was only in the 1960's that the field came into its own.  Automata theorists picked up the ideas to develop algebraic automata theory and Birkhoff was inspired by automata theory to formulate many-sorted universal algebras [[Birkhoff and Lipson: Heterogeneous algebras, 1970](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002198007080014X)].  Simula 67 report was published in the same year!

Algebraic automata theory inspired Milner to develop [simulation relations for programs](http://ijcai.org/Past%20Proceedings/IJCAI-1971/PDF/044.pdf), which in turn inspired Hoare to develop simulation relations for O-O classes [[Hoare: Correctness of Data Representations, 1972](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00289507?LI=true)].  This in turn inspired [Guttag and Horning](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=359618) to apply universal algebra techniques for specifying abstract data types (which are basically a functional programming version of classes).

So, in my view, universal algebra and the theory of data types developed in tandem, borrowing ideas and inspiration from each other.